# Bone's constraint limit X axis rotation more than 180° doesn't work

Tags: bones, constraints

I have a bone that I want the rotation around its own X axis limited to 220°.

I have checked "limit X", and set "min" to 0°, and "max" to 220°. Also set "convert" to "Local space".

When I rotate the bone, it is well limited as intended around its X axis, but beyond 180° it returns (jump) to the 0° position, until I rotate beyond 360° where it starts to rotate again.

How to allow the limitation to go beyond 180° ? What am I missing ?

*Note : I tried different "rotation orders" (XYZ, Quaternion...) but nothing changed. And also tried to check "For Transform" in the constraint panel with no more luck.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values for the Rotation Limit Constraint are clamped 180 to -180. This is a known limitation. An example:

[image]

As soon as i try to rotate the bone beyond 180° the bone snaps back to 0°

You can find more about this in the Blender manual about [Limit Rotation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Transform/Limit_Rotation).

Note: There is a small chance that this limitation will be released some time in the future. You can find more about that in the [bf-animsys](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-animsys/2014-September/000160.html) mailing list.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your time of research. I'll wait for this to be fixed... And in the meanwhile I won't limit the rotation at all :)

Comment: I found that using `Local Space` instead of `World Space` can be used to work around this limitation... provided that the bones are set up to facilitate that.

Answer (score 2):

If possible consider using the values -40 (minus) to 180 to get 220 degrees of rotation.
Perhaps adding another bone may help to build up rotation in the style that suits you.
The values are clamped 180 to -180 if I read this documentation correctly.
I get the same interaction as you explained.

Here is a technical link
http://www.blender.org/documentation/245PythonDoc/Constraint-module.html

Comment: Thanks. But, in the doc you linked, I read : "Used by Limit Rotation (LIMITROT) constraint: (...) XMAX (float): clamped to [-360.0,360.0]". And using -40° here doesn't help, because I have to limit also at 0° for "min" value...

Comment: fyi: I have started a thread in the bf-animsys mailing list about that: http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-animsys/2014-September/000159.html

Comment: @GaiaClary Thanks for adding that clarity to the situation