# Limit rotation to 180+ in X axis?

Tags: constraints

Here is my problem. I'm trying to limit the X axis to the local space, at 185 degrees, but as I rotate, it snaps at 0 as expeced. But when rotating as so, it snaps back to 0 from 180 degrees. I believe this is a bug, but I would just want to check with anybody with more knowledge about this than me. I *have* seen other threads around about this, but I saw the date and not a complete answer, so that's why I made a new one.

[image]

Comment: it looks like it can't go beyond 180°: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16055/bones-constraint-limit-x-axis-rotation-more-than-180-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted on [BlenderArtists](https://blenderartists.org/t/cannot-make-limit-rotation-constraint-go-over-180/1226368/8?u=skull_kid), here's the solution as provided below:

I simply added a limit rotation constraint to a duplicate of the main object, which I shrunk down (not necessary) and added a "limit rotation constraint" which I set to limit the X axis rotation to -30 degrees.

Then, I added a driver (right-click the desired value in the sidebar to the right in the 3D view and select "Add Driver") to the X axis for the "Axe_motor" (the main object) and set the driver's expression be "var * 6.26" in my case.

So, I multiplied -30 degrees by 6.26 times. this resulted in a perfect arc from the axe's resting position (0 degrees) to -188 degrees in X.

[image]